# Hard-wrap div around messy code

Tags: jquery, html, css, coldfusion

I have a footer, and want to do the good old fashioned "Keep the footer at the bottom no matter what" by wrapping the content in a div with `min-height: 100%`, making the footer absolute to the bottom of that container. My problem is, most files look like this:

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm" />
<cfinclude template="some-content.cfm" />
<cfinclude template="footer.cfm" />
```

Which seems easy enough, just open the container div in the header and close it in the footer. However, throughout this 12-year-old application there are countless un-closed div's and random  tags all over the place. So, when trying to wrap the sucker, the div doesn't make it all the way through the code before it gets thrown off at some point.

So the question is: Is there a happier way of keeping the footer at the bottom (I could do it in jQuery, calculating the window height and html height and whatnot, I'm really looking for something less messy if possible) or does anyone know of an obscure way to force a closing div tag to associate with it's opener?

Comment: Please try to keep your questions short and on-topic, and free of unrelated speculation.

Comment: @meagar - I personally thought the deleted "unrelated speculation" was helpful in laying out what the OP wanted and how he was thinking. But opinions differ and I defer.

Comment: Unfortunately, as convenient as that idea might seem, hacks like that are never worth the time spent thinking them up.

Comment: Opening an HTML tag in one include and closing it in another leads to tears.

Comment: @meager, I'm not sure if my idea was a good or a bad one, but what kind of community would this be if it inhibited innovation? Sometimes the solution hasn't been printed before, and it may take actual original ideas to answer these questions. Again, not saying mine was worth anything really, but I think the censorship was a little harsh seeing as how it may have inspired someone to have a truly unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a gnarly old application it's unlikely to be using any of the new HTML5 elements, so you could wrap everything in, say, `<article>` instead of `<div>`.

This idea is a bit dirty though, unless you can find a good semantic match. And Draevor is right, there are other ways to glue stuff to the bottom of the page.

Edit: [New HTML5 elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_new_elements.asp)

Comment: I like this one. Even in HTML4.1 standards I should be able to style a custom tag, such as <wrapper> </wrapper> as long as it's defined in the stylesheet, yes?

Comment: Yes, although in older IEs (if you're supporting them) your new element won't be supported unless you do a `document.createElement("wrapper")` somewhere in your JS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate window height or wrap everything in a container to keep a footer on the bottom. Create a div with your footer content at the begining or end of the html and make it stay stuck to the bottom using `position: fixed; bottom: 0` (you can also add some padding to the body if you don't want it to overlap content). If you need to support older IEs, use `position: absolute` and add a bit of Javascript to reposition it when the page is scrolled - lots of examples on the Internet about this (here's an example provided by `rip747`:  http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_244-jquery-sticky-footer)

Edit: Considering the first comment, you could also add a div after the element you want your footer to stay using jQuery. By adding it after the dom was loaded, there should be no more issues with unclosed elements.

Comment: I believe position:fixed is relative to the viewport.  I think the OP wants a footer that accomodates content of different lengths, yet sticks to the bottom of a content div.  Such a footer might be in or out of the viewport depending on content length.

Comment: @mikeY Yes, but in that case he can simply add it add the end of the content div, again there's no need to wrap everything else in a div. But in case there are still issues with unclosed tags I'll update my answer with another simple JS solution.

Comment: @ draevor cool. I was trying to think how to do it and drawing a blank.

Comment: based on the jquery suggestion: http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_244-jquery-sticky-footer

Comment: Another good solution, but my runner at the bottom (position: fixed, and seperate from the footer) keeps the document height always equal to or greater than the height of the window.